# Why the email body is showing html source code when using CodeIgniter email library?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using the CodeIgniter email library to send emails with file attachments. However, everything working fine except the email body is showing the Html source code in the mailbox. Please help to sort out this problem.

Below is the Controller page

welcome.php
----------------------------

```
$this->load->library('upload');
                $config = array(
                  'protocol' => 'sendmail',
                  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                  'smtp_port' => 465,
                  'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', 
                  'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', 
                  'mailtype' => 'html',
                  'charset' => 'utf-8',
                  'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                  'priority' => '1'
                 
                );
                $data['message']=$message;
                // Upload file
                $this->load->library('email', $config);
                $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
               
                
                $this->email->from($sendermail, $sendername);
                $this->email->to($receivermail);
                $this->email->subject($subject);
                $this->email->message($this->load->view('email',$data,true));
                $filename=null;
                if (!empty($_FILES['attachment']['name']))
                {
                    $files = $_FILES['attachment'];
                    $config_data['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
                    $config_data['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
                    $_FILES['attachment']['name'] = time().'_'.$files['name'];
                    $filename=$_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                    $_FILES['attachment']['type'] = $files['type'];
                    $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'];
                    $_FILES['attachment']['error'] = $files['error'];
                    $_FILES['attachment']['size'] = $files['size'];
                    $this->upload->initialize($config_data);
                    if ($this->upload->do_upload('attachment'))
                    {
                        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                        $this->email->attach($upload_data['full_path']);
                    }
                }
                // Upload file
                $this->email->send();
enter code here
```

Below is the View page
email.php
--------------------

```
<html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $message;?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because most likely of the content of `$data['message']=$message;`, but we don't know, how `$message` looks like.... as well as we don't know the view file email.php

Comment: The $message is coming from a form post field having ckeditor content and the email.php contains simple html tags with html tag, head tag and body tag and in between the body tag, I am just showing the $message content.

Comment: How does `email.php`  relate to the other code snippet?

Comment: email.php is the view page. This is a Codeigniter project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to configure the content as HTML

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

OR

```
$this->email->set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```

Comment: `'mailtype' => 'html'` is part of the `$config` array - doesn't that already work?

Comment: Thanks ,
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");  worked.